# java lwjgl eclipse set up error

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, lwjgl

**Error**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in
>   java.library.path     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)  at
>   org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)    at
>   org.lwjgl.Sys.(Sys.java:112)  at
>   org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.(Display.java:132)   at
>   ColoredTriangle.start(Test3d.java:12)     at Test3d.main(Test3d.java:71)

I added jar and native library. still its not working. i dont know why. image attached
[image]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Re-try doing it, also maybe there's so something wrong with your path setup, try doing it with this: http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse

Comment: I had already set the path (in image). I recently upgraded to windows 7 64bit. project files and eclipse were installed on different drive. JRE was installed in system drive. I formated and installed windows and jre on system file. if that gives any clue.

Comment: @fallenAngel I've only had experience with doing this on Windows 8, so I unfortunately have no idea what else to try

Comment: I met the same issue. I setup path for lwjgl.jar and lwjgl.jnilib. but when I try to compile my code, I got "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path". Don't know what is going on wrong. I did exactly as the link given above did.

Answer (score 0):

I don't undestand how this solution worked.
But just add this in the start of the main function or something.

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("Path to library/natives/youros").getAbsolutePath());
```

Note: I got this solution from somewhere else.

Comment: Link to question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346632/java-error-no-lwjgl64-in-path