# Unable to find the right JVM options

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, slick2d

Alright, first and foremost, I am new to Java, but not to programming.
For a personnal project I decided that I should use Slick2D, a graphics library in java, and I am running into one problem I haven't been able to fix for now.

Considering the following:

- I use Netbeans
- I'm currently on linux

From what I understand, slick2d uses lwgjl. I have followed the instructions on the following page:
[Setting up Slick2D for netbeans](http://slick.ninjacave.com/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_Slick2D_with_NetBeansIDE)

My problem I think is giving my JVM the right options.
Currently the ones I set are:

**-Djava.library.path=/home/karel/Téléchargements/slick/native/unix**

Here is the current error output I get:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl64     in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
at jcoinche.client.JcoincheClient.main(JcoincheClient.java:29)
/home/karel/.cache/netbeans/8.1/executor-snippets/run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

My code is as follow (well, the part that needs a library, and doesn't work - it's all tutorial material, by the way. Nothing I made myself):

```
package jcoinche.client;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import static jcoinche.client.Game.gamename;
import static jcoinche.client.Game.xSize;
import static jcoinche.client.Game.ySize;
import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class JcoincheClient 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   Socket socket;

   AppGameContainer appgc;
   try
   {
        appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game(gamename));
        appgc.setDisplayMode(xSize, ySize, false);
        appgc.setTargetFrameRate(60);
        appgc.start();
   }
catch(SlickException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Game.java:

```
package jcoinche.client;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.*;

public class Game extends StateBasedGame
{

   public static final String gamename = "MyGameName";
   public static final int play = 0;
   public static final int xSize = 400;
   public static final int ySize = 300;

   public Game(String gamename){
      super(gamename);
      this.addState(new Play());
   }

   public void initStatesList(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException{
      this.getState(play).init(gc, this);
      this.enterState(play);
   }

}
```

Play.java:

```
package jcoinche.client;

import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.BasicGameState;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class Play extends BasicGameState
{
  public Play() 
        {

    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg)
        throws SlickException 
        {

    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)
            throws SlickException 
        {

    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta)
            throws SlickException 
        {

    }

    public int getID() 
        {
        return 0;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you of the absence of a file named 'lwjgl64'. You are getting an UnsatisfiedLinkError, which according to the Java Documentation, is:

```
Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.
```

Now, are you using Slick2D alone? Or do you have LWJGL and Slick2D? Slick2D is not standalone; you need LWJGL to run it. I suggest getting LWJGL from [their site,](https://lwjgl.org/download) and add it's native folder to the classpath.

From the Slick2D docs, they write this:

```
   -Djava.library.path=<lwjgl-X.X path>/native/<linux|macosx|solaris|windows>
```

[Source](http://slick.ninjacave.com/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_up_Slick2D_with_NetBeansIDE)

Comment: When you download slick, you actually got a few lwgjl.jar files in it... But I think I'm starting to understand the problem. I'm going to do a few tests and come back.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few answers on stack that may help you solve this issue as it is clear from the error that it is caused by a linking error to LWJGL64. One post with a number of solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30346632/java-error-no-lwjgl64-in-path) offers a number of solutions, though targeted at the eclipse IDE specifically the general solution applies:

To quote from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6588799/when-i-run-the-jar-i-get-a-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path-error) @Ben Jackson

> LWJGL needs the native components for your particular platform to be
>   in java.library.path. These are in the subdirectory native in the
>   LWJGL distribution and end in .so on Linux, OSX and Solaris and .dll
>   for windows.

Other potential examples solving the error:
[Setting up natives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19344914/getting-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-lwjgl-in-java-library-path)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, this is a bit embarassing, but I understood what my problem was and it was a simple misunderstanding of the link I gave (instructions on how to install and use slick2D on netbeans):

In fact, my problem was that, because of the lwgjl.jar and other similar files in the slick2D folder, I thought lwgjl was, in the end, included in the slick folder.

As such, for the last step, I gave to my JVM a path directing it to the slick library folder, while it was, this time, asking for lwgjl files, causing the errors shown above.

I changed that path to the lwgjl/native/linux folder, and everything is now working perfectly.
Thanks for your answers, they helped greatly.